# Java: regular expressions.Create reg to validate path to file

Tags: java, regex

I need to create regular expression that would validate path to file. It should approve such strings like:

```
c:\
c:\dir1\file.txt
c:\dir1\dir2\file.txt
```

and so on.
I tried to create it.Result:

```
(c|C):(\\\w{0,8})*(\.\w{1,3})?
```

In [gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) everything OK, but when I compile this pattern in Java none of the previous rows are not tested.

Java code:

```
p = Pattern.compile("(c|C):(\\\w{0,8})*");
m = p.matcher(arguments);
result = m.matches();
```

Comment: Show us what you have already.

Comment: Did you escape the `\\` when you wrote the pattern as a Java string?

Comment: My code in java         p = Pattern.compile("(c|C):(\\\w{0,8})*");
   m = p.matcher(arguments);
   result = m.matches();

Comment: This should be 4 backslashes, not three.

Comment: It is not that easy as it looks. Path can be absolute or relative, can contain drive letter or not, may be UNC path, does not have to use backslashes but may use slashes (on windows too). File may have an extension or not, extnesion does not have to be 3 char wide. Path may also contain /../ or /./. Path can contain brackets, dashes, underscores (not only characters) etc ......

Comment: why 4? The first and second mean "\", \w mean any leter

Comment: @user2462686 This is java, not perl.  See my explanation.  For example, you need "\\w" in your regex, not "\w".  No idea why I was downvoted.

Comment: Every backslash in Java String must be backslashed so for your regex to contain '\w' your string must have '\\w'. Use Pattern.toString() to verify how your regex really looks like to Java.

Comment: @user2462686: BTW - first rule - before you paste any code - verify compiler's output. Java compiler will not allow you to place 3 consecutive backslashes in a String. It will not even compile.

Answer (score 0):

I just edited your example code to work:

```
String regex = "[cC]:(?:\\\\\\w{0,8})*(?:[.]\\w{1,3})?"
```

The regular expression `\\` matches a single backslash since `\` is a special character in regex, and hence must be escaped, but once we put this in quotes, aka turn it into a `String`, we need to escape each of the backslashes, yielding `"\\\\"`.  We need the additional two `\\` for `w`.

Comment: Explanation for downvote?  I followed OP's restrictions and gave an explanation...

Comment: No problem.  Since you're new to SO, here take the [tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: what mean ?: in this expression?

Comment: It means it's a [non-capturing group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group).

Comment: @user2462686 No problem.  If you feel that I have answered your question, could you please mark my answer as accepted by clicking the check mark?  Thanks.  Good luck!